# Own ExecutorService used to create CompletableFuture does not terminate

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I'm trying to use my own `ExecutorService` to create a set of `CompletableFuture`s to chain several process steps. These steps might throw exceptions.

When they do, it seems to me the thread in the `ExecutorService` is not released although I'm trying to handle this case.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        Supplier<?> throwingException = () -> { throw new RuntimeException("throw " + counter.incrementAndGet()); };
        Function<String, CompletableFuture<?>> process =
                url -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(throwingException, executor)
                        .exceptionally(Scratch::log);
        var collect = IntStream.range(1, 10).mapToObj(i -> "url" + i)
                .map(process)
                .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
        final CompletableFuture<Void> together = CompletableFuture.allOf(collect);
        System.out.println("joining");
        together.exceptionally(Scratch::log).join();
        System.out.println("finished");
        if (executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("exiting cleanly");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not terminated");
        }
        executor.submit(() -> System.out.println("still executing"));
    }
    static <T> T log(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 1
joining
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 3
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 4
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 5
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 6
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 7
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 8
java.lang.RuntimeException: throw 9
finished
not terminated
```

The process started by this also isn't terminated (which is how I noticed).

It seems to me this should mean there are no threads left in the `ExecutorService` at this point, but that doesn't seem to be the case; if we lower the thread pool capacity, it will still run all submitted tasks, and if we add submit another after the failed termination (eg `executor.submit(() -> System.out.println("still executing"));`), it will get executed.

If we don't pass our own `ExecutorService` to the `CompletableFutre::supplyAsync`, the process will terminate as expected.

I also tried other versions of handling the exceptional state (like using `together.whenComplete()`), but that has the same result.

Why is this happening, and how can I make sure the `ExecutorService` terminates correctly?

EDIT: I realized that it's not the exception that's causing the problem, this will occur with any task provided to `CompletableFuture` with your own executor service, which makes total sense given Eugene's reply. I'm changing the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here. First one is that when you execute *without* an explicit `Executor`, your actions run in the `ForkJoinPool`. That pool uses daemon-threads, which do not stop the VM to exit. So when your `main` is over, VM exists.

The second point is in the documentation of `awaitTermination`, actually:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution **after a shutdown request**, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

Since you did not call `shutDown` and that pool creates *non-daemon* threads, the process does not exit.